# How to show excerpt in single post in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I have an doubt of how can show the excerpt in the single post, basically below of the title H1. It is possible and how I can do it? I tried in the themes Astra, Suki and Twenty Twenty One, but not showed. Is there a theme or method for do it?

I read about this, but only find information about the excerpt as summary in recent posts of homepage, and the length of excerpt.

I send an image as example, with title and the short description, the result I want. I hope someone help me, thank you and sorry for my bad english.

[image: Example Title and excerpt in a website]

Answer (score 0):

The [Post Excerpt Block](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/post-excerpt-block/#:%7E:text=To%20add%20a%20Post%20Excerpt,the%20Post%20Excerpt%20block%20quickly.) is used to add an excerpt of a post. You can manually write the excerpt in the Editor or they can be automatically generated.

If your theme/s support Site Editor, you can create a new post template that contains the elements you require. There is a [WordPress guide](https://wordpress.com/support/templates/edit-the-single-template/) in the Docs which explains how to edit/customize the single post template.